# Reading TDMS File with python nptdms, cannot open tdms file

Tags: python

I am having issues with getting basic function of the nptdms module working. 
First, I am just trying to open a TDMS file and print the contents of specific channels within specific groups. 
Using python 2.7 and the nptdms quick start [here](http://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reading.html)

Following this, I will be writing these specific pieces of data into a new TDMS file. Then, my ultimate goal is to be able to take a set of source files, open each, and write (append) to a new file. The source data files contain far more information that is needed, so I am breaking out the specifics into their own file. 
The problem I have is that I cannot get past a basic error.
When running this code, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PullTDMSdataIntoNewFile.py", line 27, in <module>
    tdms_file = TdmsFile(r"C:\\Users\daniel.worts\Desktop\this_is_my_tdms_file.tdms","r")
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nptdms\tdms.py", line 94, in __init__
    self._read_segments(f)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nptdms\tdms.py", line 119, in _read_segments
    object._initialise_data(memmap_dir=self.memmap_dir)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nptdms\tdms.py", line 709, in _initialise_data
    mode='w+b', prefix="nptdms_", dir=memmap_dir)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\tempfile.py", line 475, in NamedTemporaryFile
    (fd, name) = _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\tempfile.py", line 244, in _mkstemp_inner
    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0600)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'r\\nptdms_yjfyam'
```

Here is my code:

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#set Tdms file path
tdms_file = TdmsFile(r"C:\\Users\daniel.worts\Desktop\this_is_my_tdms_file.tdms","r")

# set variable for TDMS groups
group_nameone = '101'
group_nametwo = '752'

# set objects for TDMS channels
channel_dataone = tdms_file.object(group_nameone 'Payload_1') 
channel_datatwo = tdms_file.object(group_nametwo, 'Payload_2')

# set data from channels
data_dataone = channel_dataone.data
data_datatwo = channel_datatwo.data

print data_dataone
print data_datatwo
```

Big thanks to anyone who may have encountered this before and can help point to what I am missing. 
Best,
- Dan

edit: 
Solved the read data issue by removing the 'r' argument from the file path.

Now I am having another error I can't trace when trying to write.

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile, TdmsWriter, RootObject, GroupObject, ChannelObject
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

newfilepath = r"C:\\Users\daniel.worts\Desktop\Mined.tdms"

datetimegroup101_channel_object = ChannelObject('101', DateTime, data_datetimegroup101)

with TdmsWriter(newfilepath) as tdms_writer:
    tdms_writer.write_segment([datetimegroup101_channel_object])
```

Returns error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PullTDMSdataIntoNewFile.py", line 82, in <module>
    tdms_writer.write_segment([datetimegroup101_channel_object])
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nptdms\writer.py", line 68, in write_segment
    segment = TdmsSegment(objects)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nptdms\writer.py", line 88, in __init__
    paths = set(obj.path for obj in objects)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nptdms\writer.py", line 88, in <genexpr>
    paths = set(obj.path for obj in objects)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nptdms\writer.py", line 254, in path
    self.channel.replace("'", "''"))
AttributeError: 'TdmsObject' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: According to the [file reading guide](http://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reading.html) and the [API docs](http://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apireference.html), you don't need to give `"r"` as a second parameter to `TdmsFile`, the class is always meant to read files only.

Comment: It was as easy as that! Thanks so much for calling that out

Comment: Now I am having another error I can't trace when trying to write. 
newfilepath = r"C:\\Users\daniel.worts\Desktop\Mined.tdms"

datetimegroup101_channel_object = ChannelObject('101', DateTime, data_datetimegroup101)

with TdmsWriter(newfilepath) as tdms_writer:
 tdms_writer.write_segment([datetimegroup101_channel_object])